# Processing huge items over Collections

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, swt

I have been working on `Collections` recently and I have a potentially huge list of items to be processed that is returned by the backend. 
For example my `List` has 100 items in it and I'm iterating over this list in the outermost `for loop`as mentioned below -

```
for (final Iterator i = listItems.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  for (final Iterator it = hugeListItems.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

  /* For each of the item in this outermost for loop I have another
     List of 1000 items to be processed in the inner for loop, 
     so that would potentially lead to huge amount of processing, in my case    
     (100*1000 times) */
  }
}
```

All these items after processing will be added to a Map.

The processing of these items takes a significant amount of time which hits the overall performance of my Application. I tried printing size of the Map inside the for loop and in Eclipse (I work on Eclipse IDE) I could see the thread execution halting at `ModelContext Thread` and the console slowly printing the size of the Map after each execution of the inner for loop (1000 items) which is really bad with respect to time-efficiency. Is there a way I could break down these operations into smaller modules and increase time-efficiency?

Could someone please suggest/advice a better approach to process these huge list of items (considering that the items returned by the backend may grow over time)? My new approach should reduce the execution time by a fair margin, otherwise the overall performance of my Application would really be bad.

Is there a more cleaner and efficient way to handle these increasingly rare scenarios?

Thank you All.

Comment: `100 * 1000` is no way near a huge amount for any computer. What do the objects look like? What kind of processing are you doing?

Comment: I just thought it may be causing an OutOfMemoryError, keeping this aside is there a cleaner and efficient way to process huge list items? like the one in my case.. Could you provide me an example of processing huge list items in a simpler and time-efficient manner?

Comment: I will also be editing my question to remove the OutOfMemoryError part in my initial post.

Comment: Any potential improvement will depending on what happens within the inner loop, and whether you can avoid doing N x M processing steps and creating N x M map entries.  If not, and if the collections keep getting bigger then your application has a serious problem.

Comment: Please post a the code within the inner loop so that we know if it can be parallelized, optimized, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but I had a similar issue with using Iterator - massive slowdown.  Have you tried to just go through the List?

```
for ( ListItem top : listItems ) {
    for ( ListItem sub : top ) {
       // Do your fun stuff here for your map
    }
}
```

For me, not creating all of those new Iterators helped a lot.

Comment: The enhanced `for` loop (aka `foreach`) is simply syntactic sugar for the `for-Iterator` loop.